react-admin: How to extend data provider (loopback4) for image upload
I have a react-admin setup with loopback4
I am trying to extend the dataProvider as suggested in the handling image upload
I get Error: Unknown dataProvider function: getList
it seems that the DataProvider might not be extending properly the getList (and I assume other function), does anyone have an idea what could be the problem?
below is the DataProvider.ts that I am using
import lb4Provider from 'react-admin-lb4'
import {
    CreateParams,
    UpdateParams,
    DataProvider,
    fetchUtils,
}   from 'react-admin'
import { httpClient } from './Auth'

const endpoint = 'http://localhost:3000'
const baseDataProvider = lb4Provider(endpoint, httpClient)

console.log('baseDataProvider contents:', baseDataProvider)
console.log('Does baseDataProvider have getList?:', !!baseDataProvider.getList)

<some code from the doc>

export const dataProvider: DataProvider = {
...baseDataProvider,
create: (resource, params) => {
  if (resource === 'fixtures') {
    const formData = createPostFormData(params)
    return fetchUtils
      .fetchJson(`${endpoint}/${resource}`, {
        method: 'POST',
        body: formData,
      })
      .then(({ json }) => ({ data: json }))
  }

  return baseDataProvider.create(resource, params)
},
update: (resource, params) => {
  if (resource === 'fixtures') {
    const formData = createPostFormData(params)
    formData.append('id', params.id)
    return fetchUtils
      .fetchJson(`${endpoint}/${resource}`, {
        method: 'PUT',
        body: formData,
      })
      .then(({ json }) => ({ data: json }))
  }

  return baseDataProvider.update(resource, params)
},
}

the 1st console.log returns
baseDataProvider contents: async (type, resource, {
pagination,
sort,
filter = {},
data,
ids,
id,
target
}) => {
  let total = null;
  if ([GET_LIST, GET_MANY_REFERENCE].indexOf(type) > -1) {
…

the second console.log return false

The last commit of react-admin-lb4 was in May 2019, React-admin was in version 2.9.1. The package may not follow the new React-admin standard. This package appears to be newer and may help you: https://github.com/loopback4/ra-data-lb4
